# mysql merge two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. I want to merge them, but to delete entries from table2 that starts with id's listed in table1.

```
id | name
---------
1  | test
2  | test2
3  | test3

id  | name
----------
122 | tester
222 | tester2
555 | testr3
```

I want to have:

```
id | name
---------
1  | test
2  | test2
3  | test3
555 | testr3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two statements here.

First, deleting the records from `table2`

```
DELETE  
FROM    table2 a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    table2 b
            WHERE   b.id LIKE CONCAT(a.ID, '%')
        )
```

Second, copy all records from `table1` into `table2`

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, name)
SELECT  id, name
FROM    table1
```